# How to get a list of drive letters on a system through a windows shell (bat, cmd)?

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-command-prompt

How do I get a list of drive letters and their associated labels on a windows system through a bat file?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will get most of it:

```
Net Use
```

If you have any drives mapped via subst you would also need to get those:

```
Subst
```

For completeness, you would do it like this in Powershell (if you are on windows 7 or have installed it):

```
gwmi win32_LogicalDisk -filter DriveType=4
```

You can also do it from the command prompt or a batch file using WMI like this:

```
wmic logicaldisk get caption,providername,drivetype,volumename
```

Comment: This doesn't list local disk drives like any internal hard drives or cdroms. Am I missing something?

Comment: Nope, I misunderstood the question. I thought that you only wanted mapped drives. I will edit.

Comment: The wmic solution should give you everything.

Comment: You need to remove the quotes from wmic logicaldisk get "caption,providername,drivetype" so that it is wmic logicaldisk get caption,providername,drivetype other wise it throws an error. EBGreen you have single handedly blown my mind for the day, I have never seen wmic even though I have been scripting various server builds for weeks and I am extremely excited to see what else I can do with it. Great job!

Comment: That's odd, when I was testing it I tried it first without the quotes because that is how you would actually do it in the WMIC console, but when I was passing the command into the console from a regular command prompt I had to add the quotes.

Comment: Is there a way to get the labels to display as well? Caption just prints the drive letter.

Comment: wmic logicaldisk get caption,providername,drivetype,volumename the VolumeName was what I was missing, if you update yours with that I will accept it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Edited

Comment: Please remove the "". I have tested this on four computers and have asked another co-worker to test this and they all require that the double quotes be removed. I want to make sure the solution is something that most people can just copy and paste and have it work.

Comment: Done. No idea why I need them on my system.

Comment: If you just run **wmic logicaldisk** you'll get a full list of all the columns that are available.

Comment: Thanks for the wmic!  I've been wanting something to do this easily for years and for some reason I never tried tht. Doh!

Answer (score 16):

To use diskpart, there is no need to create an intermediate file. Try:

```
echo list volume | diskpart
```

Comment: This is the best answer and returns the most info about the mounted drives in a beautiful format.

Comment: but it requires admin rights

Answer (score 11):

```
@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "_DRIVE.LETTERS.FREE=Z Y X W V U T S R Q P O N M L K J I H G F E D C B A "
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=: " %%a in ('wmic logicaldisk get deviceid^,volumename') do (
   set "_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED=!_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED!%%a,%%b@"
   set "_DRIVE.LETTERS.FREE=!_DRIVE.LETTERS.FREE:%%a =!"
)
set _DRIVE.LETTERS.USED=%_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED:~0,-2%
set _DRIVE.LETTERS.USED=%_DRIVE.LETTERS.USED:,@=, @%
set _DRIVE.LETTERS
```

Fast, flexible and efficient. Although a little complex.

Comment: I don't know what versions of Windows this works on but I just tested it on my Win 7 and XP machines and got the following output from both: `   DRIVE LETTER(s):USED: " ="
   DRIVE LETTER(s):FREE: "!TMP_FREE_DRIVE_LETTERS!"`

Comment: Sorry, you need to put this in the beginning of the batch file. setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

Comment: I've edited your answer to include the missing line. It works now. +1

Answer (score 7):

inspired by Scott

```
for %i in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do @%i: 2>nul && set/pz=%i <nul
```

also shows CD drive letters and network mounted disk letters. No need to have admin rights.

Comment: simple and works

Comment: "i was unexpected at this time."

Comment: @BeritLarsen you need to double up % symbols if running it as a batch file rather than on the command line.

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is *lucky* enough to be using Vista (Vista Ultimate SP2 b6002, in my case) and the **gwmi** and **wmic** snippets given here don't work exactly, here is what I did to make it work.

For **gwmi**, if you receive no output, try changing the DriveType to 3.  If still having problems, remove the -filter option altogether and analyze output.

```
gwmi win32_LogicalDisk -filter DriveType=3
```

For **wmic**, if you receive "Invalid GET Expression", then try putting the *get* expression in quotes:

```
wmic logicaldisk get "caption,providername,drivetype,volumename"
```

Answer (score 5):

```
mountvol
```

sample output

```
\\?\Volume{11197e59-f977-11dd-afc6-111e6f6e6963}\
   *** NO MOUNTING POINT ***

\\?\Volume{11197e59-f977-11dd-afc6-111e6f6e6963}\
   D:\

\\?\Volume{11197e59-f977-11dd-afc6-111e6f6e6963}\
   C:\

\\?\Volume{11197e59-f977-11dd-afc6-111e6f6e6963}\
   E:\
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
echo list volume > scriptdiskpart
diskpart/s scriptdiskpart
del scriptdiskpart
pause
```

Comment: I tried this one and it didn't work. I think there needs to be a space in front of the /s but even with that change it didn't work. I put the above in a file, d.bat and I see the diskpart window flash up but then disappear and the cmd shell where I'm running this then shows the pause running.

Answer (score 2):

This site has a much simpler set of calls:

http://en.code-bude.net/2013/02/23/show-all-drives-in-command-prompt/

Show local drives:

wmic logicaldisk get deviceid, volumename, description

---

If you want to show only drives of a particular type, the wmic command can be further expanded to include a where clause.

wmic logicaldisk where drivetype=2 get deviceid, volumename, description

Types

0 => Unknown

1 => No Root Directory

2 => Removable Disk

3 => Local Disk

4 => Network Drive

5 => Compact Disc

6 => RAM Disk

Answer (score 1):

```
for %a in (c: d: e: f: g: h: i: j: k: l: m: n: o: p: q: r: s: t: u: v: w: x: y: z:) do @vol %a 2>&1 | find "drive"
```

I found the diskpart approach reports DVD drives with no disc inserted, and doesn't report SD cards with valid drive volumes

Comment: does not work for windows xp

Answer (score 1):

```
for %%p in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do if exist %%p:\nul your_command_and_parameters_here
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat kludgy, but works from a batch file:

```
echo LIST VOLUME > temp.txt && diskpart /s temp.txt && del /q temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Although it has enough answer, I'd like to add one when you want to use it in batch file. If you get "Invalid GET Expression", you could put a ^ before the ',', like below:

```
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2,3,4 " %%i in (`wmic logicaldisk get caption^,providername^,drivetype^,volumename 2^>NUL`) do echo %%i %%l
```

Comment: What does this `^` do here?

Comment: It is cmd.exe's escape character, similar to \ in Unix like shells.

Answer (score 0):

Using `wmic` in a `for` loop to determine all the available drives.

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2*delims==" %%i in ('wmic logicaldisk get caption /value') do for /f "delims=" %%d in ("%%i") do echo %%d
```

There is also this little hack using exit codes `65` to `90` converted to ascii which will return all Alpabetical characters `A` to `Z` with all credit to Aacini.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /L %%i in (65,1,90) do cmd /C exit %%i & if exist "!=ExitCodeAscii!:" echo !=ExitCodeAscii!:
```

Answer (score -1):

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT EXIST A: GOTO B
:A
VOL A:
:B
IF NOT EXIST B: GOTO C
VOL B:
:C
IF NOT EXIST C: GOTO D
VOL C:
:D
IF NOT EXIST D: GOTO E
VOL D:
:E
IF NOT EXIST E: GOTO F
VOL E:
:F
IF NOT EXIST F: GOTO G
VOL F:
:G
IF NOT EXIST G: GOTO H
VOL G:
:H
IF NOT EXIST H: GOTO I
VOL H:
:I
IF NOT EXIST I: GOTO J
VOL I:
:J
IF NOT EXIST J: GOTO K
VOL J:
:K
IF NOT EXIST K: GOTO L
VOL K:
:L
IF NOT EXIST L: GOTO M
VOL L:
:M
IF NOT EXIST M: GOTO N
VOL M:
:N
IF NOT EXIST N: GOTO O
VOL N:
:O
IF NOT EXIST O: GOTO P
VOL O:
:P
IF NOT EXIST P: GOTO Q
VOL P:
:Q
IF NOT EXIST Q: GOTO R
VOL Q:
:R
IF NOT EXIST R: GOTO S
VOL R:
:S
IF NOT EXIST S: GOTO T
VOL S:
:T
IF NOT EXIST T: GOTO U
VOL T:
:U
IF NOT EXIST U: GOTO V
VOL U:
:V
IF NOT EXIST V: GOTO W
VOL V:
:W
IF NOT EXIST w: GOTO X
VOL W:
:X
IF NOT EXIST X: GOTO Y
VOL X:
:Y
IF NOT EXIST Y: GOTO Z
VOL Y:
:Z
IF NOT EXIST Z: GOTO END
VOL Z:
:END
```

Comment: Um, wow. So if you can distill that into something that would actually just output the drive letters and labels that exist on the system that would be closer to the answer to the question though this is it least movement in the right direction.

Comment: I'm getting down-voted for providing a solution that meets the criteria? Wow...

Comment: Well, for one thing, it produces errors for drives that exist but contain no media, such as a CD/DVD drive.